# Run powershell Scripts INSIDE python script

Tags: python-3.x, function, powershell

I am trying to run a powershell script with in a python script.
My idea was to do something like:

```
#pythonscript.py


def windowsupdate():

    #Somehow call all of this powershell code within the file

    Write-Host("Installing module PSWindowsUpdate if not already installed... ")
    Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate
    Write-Host("PSWindowsUpdate is now installed.")
    Write-Host("")
    Write-Host("Getting Windows Updates...")
    Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
    $updates = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-Wulist -verbose}
    $updatenumber = ($updates.kb).count
    if ($null -ne $updates){
        Get-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install | Out-File C:\PSWindowsUpdate.log
        do {$updatestatus = Get-Content c:\PSWindowsUpdate.log
            "Currently processing the following update:"
            Get-Content c:\PSWindowsUpdate.log | select-object -last 1
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
            $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
            $installednumber = ([regex]::Matches($updatestatus, "Installed" )).count
            $ErrorActionPreference = ‘Continue’
        }until ( $installednumber -eq $updatenumber)
    }
    Remove-Item -path C:\PSWindowsUpdate.log


#call function
windowsupdate() #opens up a powershell window and goes through the code then when completed close
```

If there is any way to do something similar to this without the need of creating a seperate powershell file that would be the best case scenario. If not and it needs to be in its' own file that is okay too, and if it needs to be this way, how would I call the function from within python?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to achieve what you are trying to do is by using `subprocess.Popen`. This function can call command-line/terminal commands from within a python script. It can be used like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen()
```

Where your command is placed between the two brackets.

A Powershell command can be executed from the command line using the command line (see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1080239/run-powershell-command-from-cmd)):

```
powershell -command ""
```

Where your command is between the two quotation marks.
Since subprocess.Popen can call a command line command, you can call a powershell command through it. Here's an example using your first ps command:

```
import subprocess
command='Write-Host("Installing module PSWindowsUpdate if not already installed...")'
subprocess.Popen('powershell -command '+"'"+command+"'")
```

Alternatively, you can use subprocess.run to execute the command. The only difference it that subprocess.run executes the command and then your script continues, while subprocess.Popen runs the command while your script continues.

If you want the command to do it's thing silently (eg. without opening powershell), pass `stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True` to `subprocess.Popen` with your command.
You can print the output directly with something like:

```
stdout_value = process.communicate()[0]
print (stdout_value)
```

Where process is your subprocess.Popen() object.
Now onto completing all your commands:

If you want to print the output of your commands, you can use:

```
import subprocess
def call_command(command):
    process=subprocess.Popen('powershell -command '+"'"+command+"'", stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    stdout_value = process.communicate()[0]
    return stdout_value

print(call_command('Write-Host("Installing module PSWindowsUpdate if not already installed... ")'))
```

Simply use call_command for each command and you're done. You will see some extra characters in the output (eg. `\n` or `\r`), these are included by default for powershell to actually create a newline, etc. Basically, if you don't want them, you can remove them yourself (eg. `string.replace('\n', '')`)

If you want to actually open powershell, calling `subprocess.Popen` for each line will open one powershell terminal per line, which I don't think you'd want. I would take some more trickery to call all the commands in one powershell terminal:

One thing you could do is put your powershell commands in a file with the .ps1 file extension.you can then call it with subprocess.Popen and run it altogether in a powershell terminal.
For example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("C://path/to/your/file/myfile.ps1")
```

But you'd have to have another file, not just your python script.

Or:

your could combine all your commands into one:

```
commands = """ Write-Host("Installing module PSWindowsUpdate if not already installed... ")
Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate
Write-Host("PSWindowsUpdate is now installed.")
Write-Host("")
Write-Host("Getting Windows Updates...")
Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
$updates = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-Wulist -verbose}
$updatenumber = ($updates.kb).count
if ($null -ne $updates){
    Get-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install | Out-File C:\PSWindowsUpdate.log
    do {$updatestatus = Get-Content c:\PSWindowsUpdate.log
        "Currently processing the following update:"
        Get-Content c:\PSWindowsUpdate.log | select-object -last 1
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
        $installednumber = ([regex]::Matches($updatestatus, "Installed" )).count
        $ErrorActionPreference = ‘Continue’
    }until ( $installednumber -eq $updatenumber)
}
Remove-Item -path C:\PSWindowsUpdate.log"""
```

Then run it with subprocess:

```
import subprocess;
subprocess.Popen(["powershell","& {" + command+ "}"])
# or subprocess.Popen('powershell -command' + command)
```

To print it in the terminal instead of opening powershell, use:

```
import subprocess;
subprocess.Popen(["powershell","& {" + command+ "}"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout_value = process.communicate()[0]
return stdout_value
```

That should be it!

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work, though I didn't test it:

```
def windowsupdate():
    pscommand = ' Write-Host("Installing module PSWindowsUpdate if not already installed... ")
    Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate
    Write-Host("PSWindowsUpdate is now installed.")
    Write-Host("")
    Write-Host("Getting Windows Updates...")
    Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
    $updates = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-Wulist -verbose}
    $updatenumber = ($updates.kb).count
    if ($null -ne $updates){
        Get-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install | Out-File C:\PSWindowsUpdate.log
        do {$updatestatus = Get-Content c:\PSWindowsUpdate.log
            "Currently processing the following update:"
            Get-Content c:\PSWindowsUpdate.log | select-object -last 1
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
            $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
            $installednumber = ([regex]::Matches($updatestatus, "Installed" )).count
            $ErrorActionPreference = ‘Continue’
        }until ( $installednumber -eq $updatenumber)
    }
    Remove-Item -path C:\PSWindowsUpdate.log'

    import subprocess;
    process=subprocess.Popen(["powershell","& {" + pscommand + "}"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
    result=process.communicate()[0]
    print (result)

windowsupdate()
```